# Set "Move and Size With Cells" for checkbox created in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I've created a spreadsheet which has a lot of checkboxes in it within columns. Occasionally I am finished with a column, and wish to hide it from view.

However if I hide the column, it does not hide the checkboxes in that column.

If I manually change the checkbox properties to "Move and Size With Cells" this fixes the problem. But as I said there are a lot of checkboxes, and I create them with a macro.

So I tried to add the following to the VBA which creates the macro:

```
CBX.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
```

But it doesn't make the change.

Any ideas?

Here is the full VBA:

```
Sub CellCheckboxReview()
Dim myCell As Range
Dim myRng As Range
Dim CBX As CheckBox

With ActiveSheet
    'remove comment if you want to delete all .CheckBoxes.Delete
    Set myRng = .Range(ActiveCell.Offset(19, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(23, 0))
End With

For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
    With myCell
        Set CBX = .Parent.CheckBoxes.Add _
                    (Top:=.Top, _
                     Left:=.Left, _
                     Width:=.Width, _
                     Height:=.Height)
        CBX.Name = "Checkbox_" & .Address(0, 0)
        CBX.Caption = "" 'or what you want
        CBX.Value = xlOff
        CBX.LinkedCell = .Address(external:=True)
        CBX.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        .NumberFormat = ";;;"
    End With
Next myCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The option `xlMoveAndSize` is not available for individual checkboxes, not even in the GUI of Excel. However, you can apply it if you `Group` your checkboxes.

```
Sub CellCheckboxReview()
    Dim myCell As Range, myRng As Range, CBX As CheckBox
    Set myRng = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(19, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(23, 0))

    Dim ar(1 To 5) As String ' <-- an array to be used to group the checkboxes
    Dim i As Long: i = 1
    For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
        With myCell
            Set CBX = .Parent.CheckBoxes.Add _
                        (Top:=.Top, _
                         Left:=.Left, _
                         Width:=.Width, _
                         Height:=.Height)
            CBX.Name = "Checkbox_" & .Address(0, 0)
            CBX.Caption = "" 'or what you want
            CBX.value = xlOff
            CBX.LinkedCell = .Address(external:=True)
            'CBX.Placement = xlMoveAndSize  ' <-- this has no effect for an individual checkbox
            .NumberFormat = ";;;"
            ar(i) = CBX.Name ' <-- add the shape's name to the array, for grouping later 
            i = i + 1
        End With
    Next myCell

    ' now group the checkboxes then set the desired placement
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(ar)
        .Group
        .Item(1).Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: That's fantastic, thanks a lot for your help! I had to remove the Cells(1, 1).Activate as it moved the checkbox locations and cleared the current values in column A. Other than that it worked perfectly.

Comment: @JarrodP yes that line is useless indeed. I actually did not change your code's body, I just added the grouping and Placement.