# VBA xlmoveandsize property to checkbox does not work

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that should automatically create checkboxes.

```
Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 10), Cells(i, 10))
Set chkb = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
With chkb
    .Caption = ""
    .Value = xlOff
    .LinkedCell = "S" & i
    .Display3DShading = False
    .Name = "Check_" & (i - beginningRow + 2) / 2
    .OnAction = "checkS"
    .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
End With
```

But when I hide the rows it does not work and I keep seeing them. Any suggestion?

Comment: Remove the double quotes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42015672/set-move-and-size-with-cells-for-checkbox-created-in-vba

Comment: I have updated it a bit

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42022117/4926357) especially the last part. It indicates that if you *group* the checkboces you can then set easily the `.Placement = xlMoveAndSize`. You can ungroup them afterwards if needed.